# Sequelize upsert boolean not working

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I am trying to use the upsert method in Sequelize, but I am getting inconsistent boolean returns.  It seems like the *updatedData* argument is always false, despite the fact that the data updates in the DB.  Here is my code:

```
router.post('/deploy', function (req, res) {
    var data;
    data = req.body;

    //Update data in mySQL
    db.site.upsert({
        name: data.name,
        templateId: data.templateId,
        siteName: data.siteName,
        domain: utils.formatDomain(data.domain),
        mainEmail: data.mainEmail,
        mainPhone: utils.removePhoneNumberFormat(data.mainPhone),
        mainExt: ''
    }, {
        where: {
            domain: data.domain
        },
    }).then(function (updatedData) {
        console.log(updatedData);
        if (updatedData) {
            console.log('New data written successfully');
            return res.status(200).send('New data written');
        } else {
            console.log('Data did not change from the origin');
            return res.status(200).send('Nothing changed');
        }
    }).catch(function (e) {
        console.log('Deploy Controller Error: s% ', e);
        return res.status(500).end('unexpected_error');
    });
});
```

I am sure I am doing something wrong here, but any help or feedback would be much appreciated.  Thanks and I hope you are having a nice day. :)

Comment: I've tried to put together a repro of this (here: https://github.com/cfogelberg/sequelize-playground/tree/master/tests/08-mysql-upsert-not-working) but I find that upsert is always returning true. 

I've dug into this a little bit and it seems to be because rowCount is always 1 (relevant source: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/0de404640d4c71e2d1f1259356650dfb586a248b/lib/query-interface.js#L566).

This is using MySQL version 5.5.46, node-mysql version 2.9.0 and sequelize 3.13.0. What version DB, node-mysql and sequelize are you using?

Comment: Thanks @cfogelberg.  I am using node v4.2.1, MySql v5.6.27, and Sequelize v3.3.2.  What types of options do I have as a work around?  I am new to Sequelize.  Thanks again!

Comment: looking into this some more I'm afraid I've been unable to repro updatedData === false with Sequelize 3.3.2, 3.13.0 or 3.14.0. If it would be helpful to post some work arounds anyway just let me know and I'll put them down as a proper answer to this question.

Comment: @cfogelberg I think it would helpful, if you don't mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure thing - here are three workarounds, HTH :)

**Workaround 1: Using two Sequelize calls**

Instead of using `upsert` you could use `findById` (or `count`) and then do an `insert` or `update` depending on what the first call returns. This will not be as quick as an upsert but depending on your perf needs it could be fine. Some code:

```
find_mutate: function find_mutate(id, data) {
  return models.site.findById(id)
  .then(function insert_or_update_instance(instance) {
    if(instance !== null) {
      return instance.update(data);
    }
    else {
      return models.site.create(data);
    }
  });
},

count_mutate: function upsert_using_count_mutate(id, data) {
  return models.site.count({ where: { domain: id } })
  .then(function insert_or_update_instance(count) {
    if(count !== 0) {
      return models.site.update(data, { where: { domain: id } });
    }
    else {
      return models.site.create(data);
    }
  });
}
```

See [here](https://github.com/cfogelberg/sequelize-playground/tree/master/tests/08-mysql-upsert-not-working) for a test script demonstrating this.

**Workaround 2: Manually building a raw query**

I haven't included this in the github examples just linked to, but you could also build and execute an upsert query manually using `Sequelize.query`. I would not recommend this:

- Potential vulnerability to [SQL injection attacks](https://xkcd.com/327/)
- Resulting code would be horrible to maintain and error check

That said, here is an example query for MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO `site` (`name`,`domain`,`sq_created_at`,`sq_updated_at`) VALUES ('name1','instance1','2015-11-20 13:24:50','2015-11-20 13:24:50') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `name`=VALUES(`name`), `domain`=VALUES(`domain`), `sq_updated_at`=VALUES(`sq_updated_at`);
```

**Workaround 3: More debugging**

Of the 3 workarounds, figuring out and fixing the underlying issue is probably your best move. `upsert` as written works*, therefore it might be that the behaviour you reported is actually being caused by another bug elsewhere in your code.

*Caveat: Probably unrelated: [#4885](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4885)

Some pointers for that, possibly redundant or not new for you:

- [`node-debug`](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) is a great tool.
- Logging the SQL and inspecting the value of [`rowCount`](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/query-interface.js#L548) could also be useful

**NB: Upsert and `where`**

In your code example you specify a where condition. `upsert` builds its own where clause based on the object's primary key so this option key is not needed.